# Creating multiple virtual adapters over a single physical NIC

Tags: networking

First a little context: The internet speeds on my college networks are bound by IP, and they are pathetically low. On windows, I have managed to create upto 15 virtual adapters by use of SoftEther VPN. Each of these acts as a physical adapter and gets an IP address from the network. By use of dispatch-proxy, I managed to boost by download speeds on IDM or any multi-threaded download manager from .1 MBps to 2 MBps. I want to replicate something similar on ubuntu, without use of SoftEther if possible. VLAN's would work the way i want? Or is there something else I could? Any help would be greatly appreciated because there is nothing worse than slow internet.

Answer (score 2):

Use this link for help on VLAN configuration 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/vlan

**OR**

To add a new virtual network interface, based on an existing (physical) interface.

The below example is a virtual IP based on eth0 (physical)

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.0
network xxx.xxx.xxx.0
broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.0
network xxx.xxx.xxx.0
broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

auto eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.0
network xxx.xxx.xxx.0
broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

save the file and restart the networking services

> sudo invoke-rc.d networking restart

now run `sudo ifconfig -a` should be able able to see all above configured interfaces